# Making tree hash to correct path

Tags: perl, recursion, tree

I have a hash variable as a tree:

```
\%data = {
   'node' => {
      'RN:4' => {
         'next' => {
            '1' => {
               'RN:23' => {
                  'next' => {
                     '1' => {
                        'RN:29' => {
                           'end' => 1
                        }
                     },
                     '2' => {
                        'RN:32' => {
                           'next' => {
                              '1' => {
                                 'RN:30' => {
                                    'end' = 1
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

I want to convert this tree to correct paths like this:

```
1, RN:4 >> RN:23 >> RN:29
2, RN:4 >> RN:23 >> RN:32 >> RN:30
```

I have tried some recursive code but alway get wrong path.
Help me please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure is wholly too complicated. Hashes are being used as arrays, and it would be easier if the id wasn't used as the key. It would be better if a node looked like this:

```perl
{
   id => ...,
   children => [ ... ]
}
```

The structure would become

```perl
[
   {
      id => 'RN:4',
      children => [
         {
            id => 'RN:23',
            children => [
               {
                  id => 'RN:29',
                  children => []
               },
               {
                  id => 'RN:32',
                  children => [
                     {
                        id => 'RN:30',
                        children => []
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

You need the id of all ancestors so we pass a long a list of the ancestors as the parameters.

```perl
use 5.016;

sub print_paths {
   my $i = 0;

   my $helper = sub {
      my $node = $_[-1];
      my $children = $node->{children};
      if (@$children) {
         __SUB__->(@_, $_) for @$children;
      } else {
         say $i, ", ", join(" >> ", map { $_->{id} } @_);
      }   
   };

   $helper->(@_);
}

print_paths($_) for @$roots;
```

---

The above assumes the ends are the nodes with no children. If your ends can have children, you have a trie. Simply add `end => 1` to the end nodes and use the following as the core of the visitor:

```perl
      if (@$children) {
         __SUB__->(@_, $_) for @$children;
      }

      if ($node->{end}) {
         say $i, ", ", join(" >> ", map { $_->{id} } @_);
      }
```

---

With your format, it's trickier (and more expensive).

- `$node->{id}` is replaced with `(keys(%$node))[0]`.
- `$node->{children}` is replaced with `$node->{$id}{next}`.
- `$node->{end}` is replaced with `$node->{$id}{end}`.
- `for my $child (@$children)` is replaced with `for (my $j=1; my $child = $children->{$j}; ++$j)`.

```perl
use 5.016;

sub print_paths {
   my $i = 0;

   my $helper = sub {
      my $node = $_[-1];
      my $id = (keys(%$node))[0];
      my $children = $node->{$id}{next};
      if ($children) {
         for (my $j=1; my $child = $children->{$j}; ++$j) {
            __SUB__->(@_, $child) for @$children;
         }
      }

      if ($node->{$id}{end}) {
         say $i, ", ", join(" >> ", map { (keys(%$node))[0] } @_);
      }   
   };

   $helper->(@_);
}

print_paths($data->{node});
```